# AngularJS unicode char not showing symbol

Tags: angularjs

see the sample code where filter return Unicode char but no symbold is coming. what i am missing in the code. Unicode char taken from http://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use/

```
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span>{{friend.name | customFilter}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp',[])
      .filter('customFilter', function () {
            return function (number) {
                if (isNaN(number) || number > 1) {
                    return number;
                } else {
                    if (number === 1) {
                        return "&#x2714;"
                    } else if (number === 0) {
                        return "&#x2718;"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [
        {
        name: 0,
        phone: '555-1276'},
    {
        name: 0,
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
    {
        name: 1,
        phone: '555-4321'},
    {
        name: 2,
        phone: '555-5678'},
    {
        name: 2,
        phone: '555-8765'}
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add $sce to your filter function param `.filter('customFilter', function ($sce) {...` and then trust your content as html like this:

```
                    if (number === 1) {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2714;");
                    } else if (number === 0) {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2718;");
                    }
```

For your html binding you can do this

```
   <span ng-bind-html="friend.name | customFilter"></span>
   <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
```

I created a simple jsFiddle to illustrate http://jsfiddle.net/byjo8upa/

Comment: what is $sce.trustAsHtml ?

Comment: Angular normally would escape the html you set in the controller (for security reasons mostly), so you need to tell him that you trust that content as html and is safe to place in the dom. You can read more about this in the Angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: one more question that why you use `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-bind` ? you could use `ng-model` too. tell me when one should use `ng-bind-html` ?

Comment: why unicode char `&#x2714;` should be consider as html for which you use `$sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2718;");` ? please guide me. thanks

Comment: can we achieve the goal with custom directives instead of custom filter? can u show me how to do the same with custom directive with sample code. thanks

Comment: one request. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jp6oq2tp/3/ and tell me what is wrong there for which not getting right output. just point out the mistake only. thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly why Angular binding escapes Unicode, but it does, so you need to sanitize it before binding. The ngBindHtml directive is used to insert the result in a secure way (You can read more about this here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). In your fiddle you are not declaring $sce in your filter's function
 `.filter('customFilter', function ($sce) {`.

Here's an example using a custom directive, no need to sanitize since you are not binding the data but setting the value into the html directly using `element[0].innerHTML` http://jsfiddle.net/os7j51b7

Comment: yes true but when i inject $sce in filter then also see right output did not come.

Comment: Delete angular-1.0.0rc4.min.js from external resources and set AngularJS version to 1.2.1 in the Javascript config -> Frameworks and Extensions

Comment: yes i checked it. when attach angular v1.2.1 then it works but when i change the version like v1.4.8 then no output comes....do u know the reason? $sec service is specific to v1.2.1?  http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jp6oq2tp/6/

Comment: As it says in the docs:
"As of version 1.2, Angular ships with SCE enabled by default."

Comment: what to do if someone using v1.4.8 then how could he/she can use $sec ? any alternative exist?

Comment: In the same way, $sce works on Angular v1.2+, check the docs for reference.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: not clear how to use $sce with ng v1.4.8. can u add some syntax. is there any change regarding $sce in syntax for ng v1.4.8?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to use the codes, you can use the characters directly, unless for some reason you are not saving your project files in UTF-8.

example:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
      .filter('customFilter', function () {
            return function (number) {
                if (isNaN(number) || number > 1) {
                    return number;
                } else {
                    if (number === 1) {
                        return "✔";
                    } else if (number === 0) {
                        return "✘"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

function HelloCntl($scope) {
    $scope.friends = [
        {
        name: 0,
        phone: '555-1276'},
    {
        name: 0,
        phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
    {
        name: 1,
        phone: '555-4321'},
    {
        name: 2,
        phone: '555-5678'},
    {
        name: 2,
        phone: '555-8765'}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng:app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="HelloCntl">
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span>{{friend.name | customFilter}}</span>
        <span>{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we achieve the goal with custom directives instead of custom filter? can u show me how to do the same with custom directive with sample code. thanks